# react testUtils simulate click on a radio button not triggering onchange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-testutils

For testing Im using JSDom, mocha, chai and ReactTestUtils.

One of my component got three radio button, that when a change is detected (`onChange`) will run a function.

Everything works in manual testing, but I cant seem to trigger the function when I use `simulate.Click` on it.

```
        var FrequencyFormInstance = ReactTestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(rootElement, FrequencyForm);
        var frequencyNode = ReactDom.findDOMNode(FrequencyFormInstance);

        var oneOfTheRadioButton = frequencyNode.children[1].children[2];

        ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(oneOfTheRadioButton);
```

then some assert show me that the function inside the component was never ran, so it never detected the change (the click on the radio button).

any clue as to why?

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: From what I rmb I changed `simulate.click` to `simulate.change` and it worked. Did you encounter the same problem?

Comment: yes, but I otherwise changed onChage handler to onClick and used Simulate.click method. As I understand it corresponds to React docs.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that is discussed here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/242

Essentially you need to use change as it is an input but also pass in the extra data.

```
var FrequencyFormInstance = ReactTestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(rootElement, FrequencyForm);
var frequencyNode = ReactDom.findDOMNode(FrequencyFormInstance);

var oneOfTheRadioButton = frequencyNode.children[1].children[2];

ReactTestUtils.Simulate.change(checkbox.getDOMNode(), {"target": {"checked": true}});
```